# Job is pending, waiting for approval, then become skipped

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline where the last stage needs approval from an authorised person. The pipeline seems to work well, and when this last stage is reached the status is "Job is pending..." as expected:

[image]

The problem is that after a certain time, the job eventually turn to "skipped" status automatically, so the person who should approve doesn't have time to do so:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't find what's causing this. How would I go about debugging this issue? Is there any log I can look at that would tell us why the job is being skipped (couldn't find any such log)? If not, any idea what can transition a job from "waiting for approval" to "skipped" without us doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that after a certain time, the job eventually turn to
> "skipped" status automatically.

According to your screenshot, you are using [approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass). When the approvers didn’t approve or reject the request until the **timeout** specified, it is an expected behavior that the stage will be marked skipped.

You can check the **timeout** setting in your resources. By default, it is set as 30 Days. You can define the timeout where you define the approvals and checks.

Please note: Maximum timeout is 30 days.
[image]

For your reference, you can find more details in the official doc: [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).

> Azure Pipelines pauses the execution of a pipeline prior to each
> stage, and waits for all pending checks to be completed. Checks are
> re-evaluation based on the retry interval specified in each check. If
> all checks are not successful until the timeout specified, then that
> stage is not executed. If any of the checks terminally fails (for
> example, if you reject an approval on one of the resources), then that
> stage is not executed

.